# Narrow down type of object field to type array via control-flow analysis for bracketed element access

Tags: typescript, narrowing

Type narrowing with control-flow analysis for bracket element access has been [improved with TypeScript 4.7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7/#control-flow-analysis-for-bracketed-element-access).

What I additionally would like to do is check whether the accessed field is an array or not. Right now, I don't know why the type-guard does not work:

`Error: Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)`

[image]

As you can see in the placeholder comment, TypeScript still thinks that the accessed field could be of type `string`, even though `isArray` should've made clear that the field is some kind of array.

What am I missing?

---

Here is a complete example:

Imagine we have a `Post` type, where some of the fields are arrays:

```ts
type Post = {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  chapters: PostChapter[];
};
```

Now, I have list of strings (keys of a `Post`), which I want to use to overwrite the value in a `Post` object dynamically:

```ts
const fieldNamesToReplace: (keyof Post)[] = ["chapters"];
```

When using that keys with bracketed access, TypeScript doesn't know that it is an array, even when you check for it via `Array.isArray`.

Btw: What does work (as a workaround?) is just creating a new object and overwriting the field, as we don't rely on the control-analysis for bracketed access.

---

Here is a playground link and the full example:

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.2#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-V6fX7PYH4yGw73I9G5uQp4iM1rZ8VqrGcXjTcLPnR+OBoAymBBFY4nAzKAgoEw4Cp0AgEBQWILJqJOXBOYeoAyJKwGRsqQAEwAMxAUB+TuJu3APPUrYQKgcBBLgvypiuWYRrom7lpuAB6AD8cyFtcJZQVALLABSOBMHGqauKRQA)

```ts
type PostChapter = {
  id: string;
  chapterTitle: string;
};

type Post = {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  chapters: PostChapter[];
};

const fieldNamesToReplace: (keyof Post)[] = ["chapters"];

const posts: Post[] = [
  {
    id: "1",
    title: "abc",
    chapters: [{ id: "1.1", chapterTitle: "def" }],
  },
];

const postsTransformed = posts.map((post) => {
  let postNew = { ...post };

  // works, because we don't rely on the type-narrowing for setting the value
  fieldNamesToReplace.forEach((fieldName) => {
    if (Array.isArray(postNew[fieldName])) {
      postNew = { ...postNew, [fieldName]: [] };
    }
  });

  // doesn't work
  fieldNamesToReplace.forEach((fieldName) => {
    if (Array.isArray(postNew[fieldName])) {
      postNew[fieldName] = [];
      // Error: Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)

      const placeholder = postNew[fieldName];
      //      ^?
    }
  });

  return postNew;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The improvements work on `string literals` and `symbols`. This means that it won't work when the key is a variable, hence your problem.

You can use a type predicate to fix this, but you won't be able to assign to that variable though.

Here's a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.2#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZ2AYQBYEMzAgJygXigG8AoKKASwBMAuKJHCgOwHMBuMqAYwy1wBUKwADYQ6DZuxIBfDiVCRYiYAWKdq44I1YdywIaM3ap5Hpmw4EdeEjTncAbQC6HWSRJc4TJFABmFCGEqADl0AFsIBH44ACUIMGF0LjEoAAoAawgQOF8lJABKZ1UHACIzPksSl3dPbxUwZSs84CLCB05ScnINKBKARhKAGk49AxSS9AAjLiGR7l4LJociSlpevoA6AcH5+xxBEXGqCF8SqGknYfJpYeqSXwBXJi59L0oEAEEcHHQQVLhJgArOjoJggfI0AGA95QL4-EAAHlBIAAfGpyDgIMAHjgmLDvr8NhRPgS-lD8jIPF4fA0kFEft5fHAcBEqKpacAEBswphUqkOfkCGjOlBRPVlMEIAB3VQrDbyjnnOTkAD0KqgUuZ6QQO0mEC46AeCGgUugVC8AHIVJjhCAoG9gKhoAoIABaJjob5wKWSPzM+hY-SsKCO6AAN3QwgeEE4-kCIXCkWicQSSQgGyZOAAoklUHy40FQhFBfhhXMKLlUnDCcTq38OZKpQ4CwmIk58oKRV0oA3pbKoPKNr2pTtmwFC4mnHQim5u9JONJ8sqoGqoObIkwrRqtbHx62k7F4olkhnmTmePm90WICWy92xVAI8J2RLpWP49enOXK3WiST4akT4dui3bcNS9THhAqBwEEuCqE+uigauoEAHoAPxzPO1xLu4GJYjieLDq4OFAA) that showcases this.

Comment: "but you won't be able to assign to that variable though"   -  so this is a limitation of TypeScript? Is there no better (-> type-safe) way to do this assignment?

Comment: The reason you cannot do that is because I'm saving that as a new variable so you cannot update it in the general case. For your own case, you're using an array, you use mutating methods to do anything you want, for instance to use slice/splice to modify it.

Comment: I was not talking about your example, but my original code: `postNew[fieldName] = []`   - isn't there a better way?